# What exactly do I have to do to make a concurrency exceptin happen in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server-2005, concurrency, transactions

I have Store Procedures here with Transactions using. Some of them raise a Concurrency Exception. When should that happen? I sit here before a client-server app with MS SQL Server 2005.

What I mean is, what exactly must a user(s) do that such an exception can occur?

Update the same datarow in a table?

What exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171936%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

> Concurrency exceptions [...] are raised when two users attempt to change the same data in a database at the same time.